# Retrieving data from SQL table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table in which all action logs are stored. It contains "user_id" (to mark user), "statement_id" (to mark statement that has been worked on), "action_date" (to mark action time) and "action_type" (to mark what action was done). A user can work on many statements on which many actions can be performed.

I need to produce a query that will show what statements were worked on at a specific time (let's say from March 1, 2018 to March 30, 2018) - that I can do. The difficulty for me is to limit the outcome. I mean precisely how to limit the outcome from this:

```
Statements that were worked on: 30, 30, 30, 18, 18, 42, 42, 42
```

To this:

```
Statements that were worked on: 30, 18, 42
```

I tried to work with queries like this one but I'm no professional. I find it difficult to understand the concept of some limiting SQL commands.

```
SELECT * FROM action_log 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND action_date >= 1519858800 
AND action_date <= 1522447200 
GROUP BY user_id 
HAVING user_id = 1 
ORDER BY id DESC
```

I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: no need to use having when using the same statement in where clause, `WHERE user_id = 1 ` and `HAVING user_id = 1 ` are same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `SELECT DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT statement_id
FROM action_log al
WHERE user_id = 1 AND
      action_date >= 1519858800 AND action_date <= 1522447200
ORDER BY statement_id DESC;
```

You might find this easier to maintain by using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT statement_id
FROM action_log al
WHERE user_id = 1 AND
      action_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-01') AND
      action_date <= UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2018-03-30')
ORDER BY statement_id DESC;
```

Comment: Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP has actually helped another problem. PHP would throw 'Unknown column '1519858800' in 'where' clause'. Using UNIX_TIMESTAMP helped it, and the query worked well. I'm so grateful for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need unique values.
In SQL there is a special statement for this.
[Use SELECT DISTINCT](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM action_log WHERE user_id = 1 AND action_date >= ﻿1519858800 AND action_date <= 1522447200 GROUP BY user_id HAVING user_id = 1 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use between for comparing action_date. And you can eliminate having condition because that is already used in where. WHERE user_id = 1 and HAVING user_id = 1 will result you the same. Hope following code will work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM action_log WHERE user_id = 1 AND action_date between '1519858800' AND '1522447200' GROUP BY statement_id ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: `action_date >= 1519858800 AND action_date <= 1522447200` and `action_date between '1519858800' AND '1522447200'` aren't identical?

Comment: Yeah it is. But between will avoid unnecessary re evaluation, which leads to query execution faster than using operators